# Concatenate two fields in one in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

In my form I have a date field that gets the current date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format and a field that auto-generates a number.

I want to populate another field in the following format:

`yyyy-mm-dd-autogenreate number`.

Where the year and month and date are the current dates of the form.

How do I do this? And I am not good at coding so if this is to be achieved through JavaScript then please be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the field doesn't have to be populated when you load a new entity, I would add this to your [onSave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d88d5f21-6385-443b-91f2-0ec0c16b1324#BKMK_OnSaveEvent) event for your form:

```
var dateFieldValue= Xrm.Page.getAttribute('datefieldname').getValue();
```

var autoNum = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('autoNumfieldname').getValue();

```
/* Date Formatting from Guido Preite's answer https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/109891/218598.aspx#218598 */
// create the yyyy-mm-dd string
var year = dateFieldValue.getFullYear()+"";
var month = (dateFieldValue.getMonth()+1)+"";
var day = dateFieldValue.getDate()+"";
var dateFormat = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

Xrm.Page.getAttribute('otherField').setValue(dateFormat + "-" + autoNum);
```

**Note** I haven't tested this so it might have an error in it, but it should get you started.

You'll also have to note that this will only get populated when the entity is created / updated on the form.  Any backend processes that create the entity will need to create the same logic.

You could also use a plugin to perform the same thing if you wanted to guarantee that no matter how the entity gets created, it has this value populated.

Comment: Hey Daryl,
I did the same thing that as above before I read this post and it works. But the standard dare format of CRM is **mm/dd/yyyy**. I want my format to be **yyyy/mm/dd-autonumber** in the new field. Any ideas on that?

Comment: And it is giving me the whole format like friday july 26th, 2013 and I want it to 2013-07-26-(random number)

Comment: @GuidoPreite, what? you wanted pretty answers?  You're on the wrong site,  you want http://pretty.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I meant my conversion date part :P

Comment: @GuidoPreite I know ;)

Answer (score 1):

For a non code approach, as long as you don't mind the process being asynchronous, use a workflow which writes both values into a single field.

Comment: inside a workflow is not possible to change the date format to yyyy-mm-dd (at least without a custom activity)

Comment: James Wood and @GuidoPreite, you guys are both brilliant.  The worfklow would also ensure that it always is updated (eventually due to the async approach)

Comment: I read somewhere that CRM 2013 will bring synchronous workflows, but no official confirmations yet.

Answer (score 0):

*https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/109891/218598.aspx#218598*

My query has been answered by Guido Preite. Go to the link to see the answer. Thank you all.